# Vanishing ideal of $Z(X^2+Y^2+1)$ in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am new to algebraic geometry and dont know what to do with the following exercise:

> What is the vanishing ideal of $Z(X^2+Y^2+1)$ in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$?
> (We defined $Z$ as the set of zeroes of a given polynomial.)

I do not understand how I should proceed now. I think I could simply write that the vanishing ideal $I$ is $I = \langle X^2+Y^2+1 \rangle$, but can I do more here?

Comment: The vanishing ideal of $Z(I)$ is $\sqrt{I}$. This is the Nullstellensatz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Justauser is more elegant and self-contained than this, but just for variety, here is a different method:

It suffices to show that $1+X^2+Y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, as then we may deduce that it is prime from the fact that $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ is a UFD.  Thus $a^n\in\langle 1+X^2+Y^2\rangle \implies a\in \langle 1+X^2+Y^2\rangle$.

Suppose we can factorise $1+x^2+y^2$ non-trivially.  Without loss of generality we then have a factorisation of the form: $$1+x^2+y^2=(1+ax+by)\left(1+\frac xa+\frac yb\right)$$

Considering the coefficients on $x,y$ we get $a=\frac{-1}a, b=\frac{-1}b$, so $a=\pm i,\,\, b=\pm i$, so the coefficient on $xy$ is $\pm2\neq 0$, yielding a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

For example, $X$ vanishes on $Z(X^2)\in \mathbb C[X]$, since $Z(X^2)=\{0\}$, but $X\not\in \langle X^2\rangle$. This simple example shows that the vanishing ideal of $Z(I)$ is not necessarily $I$.

It's easy to see that if $p(X_1, \dots, X_n)^m\in I\le K[X_1, \dots, X_n]$, then $p(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ vanishes on $Z(I)$, and Hilbert's Nullstellensatz says the converse is true if $K$ is an algebraically closed field.

That said, for this particular example, it is indeed the case that the vanishing ideal is just $\langle X^2+Y^2+1 \rangle$. This can be shown using Krull's Hauptidealsatz, but can also be done with the following elementary method.

Suppose $f(X,Y)$ vanishes on $Z(p(X,Y))$ where $p(X,Y)=X^2+Y^2+1$. Note that $Y^2 \equiv -X^2-1 \bmod p(X,Y)$, we can replace any high power of $Y$ by a polynomial of $X$, therefore $f(X,Y)\equiv g(X)Y+h(X)\bmod p(X,Y)$. As $g(X)Y+h(X)$ vanishes on $Z(p)$, so does $g(X)(-Y)+h(X)$, hence $h(X)$ vanishes on $Z(p)$ as well. This implies $h(X)$ has infinitely many zeroes, so $h(X)=0$. Therefore $g(X)Y$ vanishes on $Z(p)$ and similarly $g(X)$ will have infinitely many zeroes, hence $g(X)=0$. We conclude $f(X,Y)\equiv 0 \bmod p(X,Y)$, i.e. $f(X,Y)\in \langle p(X,Y)\rangle$.